# Can we put a condition in setInterval Timer?

Tags: javascript

let say I have recurINDEX =1, and curTime1 = 60000 and curTime = 120000

```
setInterval( recursive ,recurINDEX%2? curTime1:curTime)
```

Where recursive is a function,

```
function recursive(){
       recurINDEX++;
console.log("hello")


}
```

My goal is to run this function first after curTime1 time and then curTime time ,then keeps going.
If above is not correct, looking for a better approach.

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` at the end of `recursive`, instead of using a single `setInterval`

Comment: yes that should work, can you confirm the setInterval code is correct? i.e., the condition part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout instead
Run the recursive function with the below code

```js
let curTime1 = 60000, curTime = 120000;
let recurINDEX = 0;
let run = setTimeout(recursive, curTime1); // start the function with curTime1 delay

function recursive(){
    clearTimeout(run); // clear the timeout
    // do your logic here
    recurINDEX++;
    if(recurINDEX == 1)
    {
        run = setTimeout(recursive, curTime) // run the function 2nd time after curTime2 delay
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also doit with a combination of `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` as shown below:

```js
console.log("start:",new Date());
setTimeout(()=>{doit(),setInterval(doit,12000)},6000);

function doit(){
 console.log(new Date())
}
```

I have reduced the waiting intervals to make the demo a little faster ;-).